# Can't access/store game state object in a map

Tags: c++, state-machine, stdmap

I am trying to store an object in a list of objects (map) using a string as the key and the object as a value.

```
void GameStateManager::AddGameState(std::string name, GameState * state)
{
    gameStates.insert(std::make_pair(name, * state));
}

std::map<std::string, GameState> gameStates{};
```

I then try to read an object from the list and store it:

```
void GameStateManager::SetNext(std::string name)
{
    if (gameStates.count(name))
    {
        nextState = gameStates[name];
    }
}

void GameStateManager::SwitchState()
{
    currentState = nextState;
}

gameStateManager.SetNext("MainMenu");
gameStateManager.SwitchState();
```

which I then proceed to run:

```
currentState.HandleInput();
currentState.Update();
currentState.Draw();
```

I think there is a problem in storing the `GameState` object in the map.
When calling the above functions, the actual implemented function (for instance, `MainMenuState.Draw()`) is never executed, so I think `currentState` and `nextState` stay empty.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
gameStates.insert(std::make_pair(name, * state));
```

I had to use

```
gameStates[name] = state;
```

Noob mistake, but at least it's working now. yay.